# Supply settings.xml to a bash script containing mvn command in jenkins

Tags: bash, maven, jenkins

I am using `Config File Provider Plugin` to supply settings.xml file to my maven commands as follows -

```
steps {
       configFileProvider(
                              [configFile(fileId: 'artifactory-maven', variable: 'MAVEN_SETTINGS')]) {
          sh "mvn -Dvault.useProxy=false -s $MAVEN_SETTINGS -DskipTests=true -e -U -P autoInstallPackage"
          }
       }
```

Everything works as expected. 
Now I have another case where I am calling a bash script file that contains a logic with a few mvn commands.

```
steps {
    sh 'cd testing && ./test-spec-seleniumhub-jenkins'
}
```

The mvn commands live inside `test-spec-seleniumhub-jenkins` file. How can I supply the settings.xml file to these mvn commands.

Comment: This looks like the project does not follow convention over configuration. Why do you need to make a `cd testing`?